# angular crud add function to database

Tags: html, angular, crud

I hope you are well.

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have an API with recipes and I manage to display them in frontend but now I can't make the post route to work to insert a new recipes with success in my database. I would really appreciate if someone can tell me how can I do that.

Nodejs:

```
app.post("/recipes", (req, res) => {
  recipe = new Recipe({
    _id: req.body._id,
    title: req.body.title,
    image: req.body.image,
    description: req.body.description,
    calories: req.body.calories,
    cookingTime: req.body.cookingTime,
  });

  recipe.save(() => {
    res.json(recipe);
  });
});
```

Typescript service add recipe

```
// Add recipe
  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${uri}`, payload);
  }
```

Typescript add recipe

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addRecipeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      _id: new FormControl(''),
      title: new FormControl(''),
      image: new FormControl(''),
      description: new FormControl(''),
      calories: new FormControl(''),
      cookingTime: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
```

```
export class RecipeModel {
  _id!: String;
  title!: String;
  image!: String;
  description!: String;
  calories!: String;
  cookingTime!: String;
}
```

Recipe HTML where I display the recipes

```
<div *ngFor="let recipe of data">
      <p>
        {{ recipe.title }}
      </p>
      <img src="{{ recipe.image }}" alt="" />
      <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe.calories }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe.cookingTime }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe._id }}</p>

       <button routerLink="/add">Add a new recipe here</button>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do now is to press on the button add new recipe and to insert the values and after to see the recipe in my database and in UI, how can I manage that, thanks for you time a lot.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use Observables from RxJS ([see more about them](https://angular.io/guide/observables)) to refresh your Recipe list after CRUD operation. I recommend you to read first the bases of reactive programming with RxJS for example, if you never use it. So the POST request have to see like this:

```
// Add recipe
addRecipe(uri: string, payload: Object): Observable<RecipeModel> {
  return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${uri}`, payload).pipe(
    map((response: RecipeModel ) => response as RecipeModel ),
    catchError( error => {
      return throwError(error);
    }
   )
  );
 }
```

Then you can simply Subscribe to this method:

```
this.myRecipeService.addRecipe(myUri, myPayload).subscribe(
  responseFromServer => {
    refreshMyRecipes(); // or refresh basing in your server response
  }
)
```

This method will send a POST request to your desired URI and when the server ends proccessing your request, the anon method will execute refreshing your recipe list.

Comment: Hi,  I tried but still get some errors,  can't make the add new recipe to work from uia nd add to database..